# How can I analyze a segment of an audio file with sox?

Tags: audio, sox

I wanted to analyze 5 seconds of an audio file beginning from 50 seconds.

So I ran the following command:

```
sox audio.wav -n stat trim 50 5
```

But the output contained:

```
...
Length (seconds):     55.296000
...
```

But I expected only 5 seconds, not 55.

What did I do wrong? I thought that 50 was the start and 5 - the duration.

Comment: @dirkt: No, the second argument is a relative position unless it is prefixed by `=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effects function as a chain, so the `stat` effect feeds into `trim`, swap them around and it will work, e.g.:

```
sox audio.wav -n trim 50 5 stat
```